# dynamic form complains about number of "steps" as an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

My form allows for multiple "steps" to be submitted in the form. The steps are added via push of a button on the form via JavaScript.

The problem is django form and validating thereof:

```
class TaskForm(forms.Form):
    task_name = forms.CharField
    step_number = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        step_fields = kwargs.get('step_number', 0)
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['step_number'].initial = step_fields

        for index in range(int(step_fields)):
            self.fields['step_field_{index}'.format(index=index)] = forms.CharField()
```

This creates form with the task name as the only input field when the page is first loaded. That's expected.

I add the steps to my task through the browser, this works fine and the hidden field is incrementing.

Then I submit, but I get the error:

> TypeError at 'task-app/create-task.html'
>
> __ init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'step_number'

Obviously, the keyword argument comes from the views.py:

```
def add_task(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = TaskForm(request.POST, step_number=request.POST.get('step_number'))
            if form.is_valid():
                # do something with the form
                create_task(form)
                messages.success(request, "The task form was valid")
                return redirect('task-app:homepage')
            else:
                messages.warning(request, "The form is not valid")
                return render(request, 'task-app/create-task.html', {'form':form})
        else:
            form = TaskForm()
            return render(request, 'task-app/create-task.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you forgetting to pop `step_number` from the kwargs before you call TaskForm's super init?

You should `pop` from the kwargs rather than `get`, otherwise the form will throw an exception like you're seeing because the `super().__init__` does not expect the extra param.

```
class TaskForm(forms.Form):
    task_name = forms.CharField()
    step_number = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        step_fields = kwargs.pop('step_number', 0)
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['step_number'].initial = step_fields

        for index in range(int(step_fields)):
            self.fields['step_field_{index}'.format(index=index)] = forms.CharField()
```